# How to append the second return value, directly to a list, in Python

Tags: python

If a function returns two values, how do you append the second value directly to a list, from the function result?
Something like this:

```
def get_stuff():
    return 'a string', [1,2,3,5]

all_stuff = [6,7]
# How do I add directly from the next line, without the extra code?
_, lst = get_stuff()
all_stuff += lst
```

Comment: `all_stuff += get_stuff()[1]`

Comment: that won't give the desired effect if the second return argument is a string.

Comment: @user1054424:  That is an inane objection.  There is no good reason to think the structure of the return value is different than shown.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The question asks from a general perspective. The code was just an example. I was pointing it out b/c of that. Others might reference this question with slightly different return types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can index a `tuple` using the same indexing you would for a list `[]`. So if you want the `list`, which is the second element, you can just index the element `[1]` from the return of the function call.

```
def get_stuff():
    return 'a string', [1,2,3,5]

all_stuff = [6,7]
all_stuff.extend(get_stuff()[1])
```

Output

```
[6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `all_stuff += zip(get_stuff())[1]`

Comment: Why was this answer knocked down? It is a valid solution and is a more general case to the question.

Comment: -1.  Incorrect.  Your code gives a result of `[6, 7, [1, 2, 3, 5]]`.  The example code in the question gives a result of `[6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5]`.

Comment: Thanks anyway ;) I guess `all_stuff += zip(get_stuff())[1][0]` would fix it but not great...

Comment: but `all_stuff += get_stuff()[1]` should give the same result ;)