# How to append the multiple return values, directly to a list, in Python

Tags: python

If a function returns two values, how do you append them directly to two separate lists directly, from the function result?
Something like this:

```
def get_stuff():
    return [3,4,5], [9,10,11]

stuffed_one = [1,2,3]
stuffed_two = [6,7,8]
# How do I add directly from the next line, without the extra code?
lst_one, lst_two = get_stuff()
stuffed_one += lst_one
stuffed_two += lst_two
```

Assume `get_stuff` always returns 2 lists (including empty lists).

Comment: Yes, this is very similar to my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697061/how-to-append-the-second-return-value-directly-to-a-list-in-python?noredirect=1#comment38298510_24697061 I realised I didn't ask exactly what I needed, but it still was a valid question ;)

Comment: why not add them in the function?

Comment: I'd say you can't.  Not without replacing the existing extra code with other extra code.  For a fixed number (2) of lists, I think the code you have is the simplest and most readable.

Comment: It's going to be hard to mark any answer as correct... but some cool tricks here :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you did. You are getting a tuple of two lists, extract each of them, and append them. If you want, you can get fancy with zip(), but for a two lists cases I would not bother.

```
>>> def foo():
...     return [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
... 
>>> l1=["a", "b"]
>>> l2=["d", "e"]
>>> l1, l2=map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip((l1, l2), foo()))
>>> l1
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]
>>> l2
['d', 'e', 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: I really don't get why you decided to use that `map` call as example; it mixes a lot of other things that are simply distracting (especially for someone very new to python). It would have been much clearer to simply do: `x, y = foo(); l1 += x; l2 += x; l1; l2`. (maybe avoiding lowercase `L` since it resembles too much a `1`).

Comment: @Bakuriu: the point of the question was achieving the same in a single liner.

Comment: @StefanoBorini The question was how to make it more directly, I don't think throwing in `map()`, `lambda`, and `zip()` is more direct than the original code.  Just more complex.  KISS.

Answer (score 0):

With a slight abuse of a `for` loop, you can use `itertools.starmap`.

```
from itertools import starmap

def get_stuff():
    return [3,4,5], [9,10,11]

stuffed_one = [1,2,3]
stuffed_two = [6,7,8]

for _ in starmap(list.extend, zip([stuffed_one, stuffed_two], get_stuff())):
    pass
```

`zip` returns an iterator which supplies the tuples `(stuffed_one, [3,4,5])` and `(stuffed_two, [6,7,8])`. `starmap` will use those tuples as argument lists for successive calls to `list.extend` (note that `list.extend(stuffed_one, [1,2,3])` is essentially the same as `stuffed_one.extend([1,2,3])`). Since `starmap` returns an iterator, you just need some way to actually call each invocation of `list.extend`, which means iterating with the for loop.

Comment: Ugh! This is *obviously* a hack. If you have to use `pass` in order to make code work *something* must be broken. Using `map`/`starmap` etc with functions that *only* produce side effects is just wrong. You didn't even save any line of code respect the naive `for` loop.

Comment: I agree it's a hack, but it's not quite as bad as using a list comprehension solely for the side effect of the mapped function. No list is allocated just to be discarded; the iterator calls the function some number of times, and only the return value (`None`) is discarded, but you'd be discarding that anyway even if you made a fixed number of calls explicitly. On the plus side, this scales to any number of lists to modify (as long as the lists are already in a list or other utterable, of course).